# Manage and Edit JSON in Power Automate

Tags: json, ms-flow

I'm using **Get_Flow** action in order to get the flow definition, it seems that the format of this definition is JSON

My desire is to customise this JSON and change what it must change, and then create another flow with the new customised flow definition

Question: how can I customise that JSON in Power Automate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the JSON schema for the JSON you want to customize, you can use the "Parse JSON" action to give you a strongly typed interface in the Flow designer.  To generate a modified version you'll need to use a combination of the "Compose" Action, and the `setProperty` function in the expression.  Creating a Flow to create a Flow is not going to be a simple process, you will probably have to go through a lot of trial and error.

Comment: Indeed, I already faced these errors, and i managed to solve them. your reply is the right answer